# A shell script that give the CPU information

Tags: scripting

Can someone help me to write a shell script that'll give me the following information:

- The state of the process;
- The time it passed the process in the CPU;
- The total memory used (in KB);
- The number of open file descriptor;
- The command line that started the process; - Pid of the process initiated by this process.

It's suppose to be in JSON format and it has to look like this:

```
{
    "pid" : 2714,
    "status" : "S",
    "usageCPU" : 1233,
    "usageMemoire" : 404,
    "numFD" : 12,
    "commande line" : "/bin/bash",
    "task" :
        [
            { "pid" : 2714 },
            { "pid" : 4230 }
] }
```

And one more little thing :

Input parameters:

Your program will take the following input parameters: - The pid of the process that we would like the information. In sum to start your program will require the command: ./your_program 2714

Error Format

If you can not find the necessary information because the pid number is not good then it will return the following string: E_PID_NOT_FOUND

P.S I'm an math fac, but I have to write this, and I don't have any little idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
name_of_process=$1

ps aux\
 | grep $name_of_process\
 | grep -v "grep"\
 | awk '{print \"{\
     \"pid\" : $2,\
     \"status\" : $8,\
     \"usageCPU\" : $10,\
     \"usageMemoire\" : $4,\
     \"numFD\" : $some_field_num,\
     \"commandline\" : split($NF)[0]\
     \":[{ \"pid\" : $2},{\"pid\" : $some_field_num_too }]}'
```

So effectively I call `ps` (with `aux` flags) which gives a list of all processes and their data, pipe the output of this into `grep` to get just the line with the name of our process, pipe the output of that into `grep` again this time not looking for the phrase "grep" (trust me this is neccesary), and then finally piping the data (now just a single line) into awk.

Awk then splits the data by columns (default delimiter is TAB I think) and in awk the $number syntax corresponds to a column of the data it was given.

For numFD and ppid I had no clue what columns those would be because they're not printed by default, so maybe check the extra flags of `ps` (other than `aux`) and see what options you have available.

Comment: no problemo, let me know if there's any ambiguity - the backslashes can make everything seem a little convoluted